# ECharts - How to prevent changing background color on hover

Tags: hover, background-color, echarts, disable

I would like to prevent background-color from changing when I hover on ECharts map.
For example, see this link https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa.  How can I hover over the map but the colors of the map remain unchanged.  I do not want the background color changing (to yellow in this case) when I hover my mouse on any part of the map

Answer (score 7):

`emphasis: { ... }` similar `:hover` but you can `silent: true` to turn events off.

**Update:**

- `silent: true` it's Echarts method that suppress events for series. In this case you can use method to suppress event `mouseover` emitted by the map. Set `silent` to true no one events will not produced. According to example from question you need add row into series option:

```js
series: [{
  name: 'USA PopEstimates',
  type: 'map',
  roam: true,
  map: 'USA',
  silent: true, // <---- here
  [...]
}]
```

Almost all components has this method and you can suppress events in runtime.

- `emphasis` it's simple and easy method to define styles that will be applied to map on `mouseover` event. Take a look [official tutorial](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Overview%20of%20Style%20Customization) how to use this method:

```
series: [{
  name: 'USA PopEstimates',
  type: 'map',
  roam: true,
  map: 'USA',
  silent: true,
  emphasis: {
    label: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Can you clarify your comment, please? Is silent:true a css property?  I checked online but didn't see such.  Can you please give clear example?  Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you so much @sergey-fedorov!!

Comment: What if I want to disable certain section of pie chart, is there a way around this?

Comment: Just filter events from pie, check section and do nothing if this section the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a css work-around for now, but I was thinking there is an eCharts option to turn mouse hover action off on background color.

The css solution I used is

```
.turnOffHover{
    pointer-events: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use emphasis prop inside a serie item, to disable.

```
emphasis: {
    disabled: true,
  },
```